# Possible syntax errors with guessing game

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a number guessing game where you input a number as a user and try to get the same number that the computer chose. The computer chooses a number between 1-100 and each time you guess it tells you if you need to guess higher or lower.

The problem lies in the java script, and I'm contemplating whether I wrote something wrong or something is just not how its supposed to be. I have checked over all the id's and everything, but I'm still not getting any feedback from the code.

I wish for the code to output something when I do try and press the guess button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>GuessingGame</title>
  <style>

  </style>
  <script>
    var playerGuess = document.getElementById("guessInput").value;
    var computerGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var playAgain = true;

    function randNum(low, high) {
      var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * high + low);
      return number
    }

    function guessNumber() {
      if (playerGuess > computerGuess) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
          "Guess lower"
      } else if (playerGuess < computerGuess) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
          "Guess higher"
      } else(playerGuess == computerGuess) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
          "Good job you guessed right"
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
  <h2>The computer will choose a number between 1 and 100</h2>
  <h2>You have to try and guess what it picked</h2>
  <span><input type="number" id="guessInput">
    <button onclick="guessNumber();">Guess</button><button
    onClick="reset();">Reset</button>
    <p id="output"></p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the debugging console for errors, because they're either there, or not :P

Comment: I  created you a snippet. It gives a very clear idea

Comment: 1. Invalid HTML (span contains text, not input fields and paragraphs) and is not closed 2.  missing end curly bracket, 3. missing if  after else `else(playerGuess == computerGuess) {` 4. Accessing a field before it exists (move the code to after the HTML before the `</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your javascript code is written incorrectly, and some of your HTML is invalid. Here, I have moved the variable from the global scope to the function, as it makes more sense to make it here, and the variable will change every time you click the button, not just onload:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>GuessingGame</title>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
    <h2>The computer will choose a number between 1 and 100</h2>
    <h2>You have to try and guess what it picked</h2>
    <span><input type="number" id="guessInput"/></span>
    <button onclick="guessNumber();">Guess</button>
    <button onClick="reset();">Reset</button>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    var computerGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    var playAgain = true;

    function randNum(low,high) {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*high+low);
        return number
    }
    function guessNumber(playerGuess) {
        var playerGuess = document.getElementById("guessInput").value;
        if (playerGuess > computerGuess) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Guess lower"
        } else if (playerGuess < computerGuess) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Guess higher"
        } else {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Good job you guessed right"
        }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

You will need to write your `reset()` function for the button to do anything :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Invalid HTML (span contains text, not input fields and paragraphs) and is not closed
2. missing end curly bracket,
3. missing if  after else `else(playerGuess == computerGuess) {`
4. Accessing a field before it exists - solution : move the code to after the HTML before the `</body>` or in this case access the field in the function you call when you click
5. Not getting the guess inside the function you test it
6. Not using the randNum function

```js
function randNum(low, high) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * high + low);
  return number
}

function guessNumber() {
  var playerGuess = +document.getElementById("guessInput").value;

  if (playerGuess > computerGuess) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Guess lower"
  } else if (playerGuess < computerGuess) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Guess higher"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Good job you guessed right"
  }
}

var computerGuess = randNum(1, 10);
```

```html
<h1>Guessing Game</h1>
<h2>The computer will choose a number between 1 and 10</h2>
<h2>You have to try and guess what it picked</h2>
<div><input type="number" id="guessInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="guessNumber();">Guess</button><button onClick="reset();">Reset</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```